# Separate a row into equal interval of date and also separate the value

Tags: mysql, sql

create a new column as end date with intervals from the given input and separate the amount value in equals

table provided

| id | stdate | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1/1/2020 | 90 |
| C2 | 2/2/2020 | 100 |
| C3 | 3/3/2020 | 60 |

expected table

| id | stdate | enddt | amt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1/1/2020 | 1/3/2020 | 30 |
| C1 | 1/2/2020 | 1/3/2020 | 30 |
| C1 | 1/3/2020 | 1/3/2020 | 30 |
| C2 | 2/2/2020 | 2/2/2020 | 100 |
| C3 | 3/3/2020 | 3/5/2020 | 20 |
| C3 | 3/4/2020 | 3/5/2020 | 20 |
| C3 | 3/5/2020 | 3/5/2020 | 20 |

can you guys explain this output

Comment: How do we know to separate the amount there isn't any logic from your source table.

Comment: Are you finding amt per month from the month in the table to current month?but then why does c2 does not go to 3rd month?

Comment: Its an question from the interview conducted by Microsoft for my friend , he got this code and he also didn't crack it

Comment: He definitely missed some part of the question, how would you determine the end date?

Comment: Derived from std date and giving interval and using partition

Comment: Those dates are not in mysql format are they d/m/y or m/d/y? and derivation of start date is not clear. Derived from std date and giving interval and using partition means nothing to me.

Comment: 'can you guys explain this output - are you expecting us to explain how this result is arrived at without seeing the query which generated it?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a stored procedure to do this. Just specify the id and the end date when you call it , and it will insert into the new table. A warning is generated if the end date is older than the start date. Here is the code which I wrote in workbench:

```
delimiter //
drop table if exists n_table//
create table n_table (id varchar(5), stdate date, enddt date, amt int)//
drop procedure if exists divide_row//
CREATE  PROCEDURE divide_row (o_id varchar(5),end_date date)
BEGIN
declare counter int default 0;
declare d_diff int;
declare c_id varchar(5);
declare c_stdate date;
declare c_amount int;

select id into c_id  from o_table where id=o_id;
select stdate into c_stdate  from o_table where id=o_id;
select amount into c_amount  from o_table where id=o_id;

set d_diff=datediff(end_date,c_stdate);
if d_diff<0 then
    select 'The end_date specified must not be older than the start_date !!' as warning;

else
    lp : loop
    if counter>d_diff then
    leave lp;
    end if;

    insert n_table values (c_id, adddate(c_stdate,counter),end_date, c_amount/(d_diff+1));
    set counter=counter+1;
    end loop lp;
end if;

END //
```

Please comment on this.